# Hover over text, separate div appears

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/martaklopf/pen/apzbWv?editors=1111

HTML

```
<div class="boxes"> </div>

<div class="hoverover">
 hello
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxes {
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 display: none;
}

.hoverover:hover .boxes {
 display: block;
}
```

I am trying to do something really simple with just CSS, but I can't figure it out. I want to hover over some text and have something else appear in a **separate** div with just CSS. I thought what I have would work except that display:block seems to be somehow blocked. I tried inline and that doesn't work either. Am I missing something really obvious? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without changing the HTML (for example [like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNPyJW?editors=1111)), you just can't do that. Selectors are very limited, so at some point you need JavaScript to achieve this kind of result.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this, using only CSS, you would have to layout the appearing element after the hovered and use the adjacent (+) selector.

```css
.boxes {
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 display: none;
}

.hoverover:hover + .boxes {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverover">
 hello
</div>

<div class="boxes">boxes</div>
```